# Angular 2 ngModel two-way binding sometimes not working

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular2-forms

I have an object with a string variable that is bound to a textarea. In (ngModelChange) I have a function that checks the length of the string as it is edited and if it is too long assigns a "previous value" to the actual value. Like this:

```
t.value = t.previousValue;
```

This is not working. When I debug I see the variable being assigned and everything looks good but the data-binding doesnt update. However, if I change t.previousValue to "test", that works and the textarea is updated.

```
t.value = "test";
```

What is the difference?

Relevant code:

`<textarea type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="t.value" (ngModelChange)="isOverflowing(t)"></textarea>`

```
if (this.textArea.nativeElement.clientHeight < this.textArea.nativeElement.scrollHeight){
        if(t.value.length - t.previousValue.length > 1){
            t.value = t.previousValue;
        }else{
            t.value = t.value.substring(0,t.value.length-2);
        }
    }
    t.previousValue = t.value;
```

Comment: You are saying you did this in your ngOnChanges? You should be cautious that an infinitive change check might happen since value is keeping changing in the middle of change detection.

Comment: Can you show us your view and component code?

Comment: Can you tell us if `$scope.$apply()` solves it? Your code is not sufficient to reproduce!

Comment: This is angular 2+ so I don't think I can use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the banana-box with ngModel if you're manaully setting the change event:

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="t.value" (ngModelChange)="isOverflowing(t)"></textarea>
```

Should be:

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="t.value" (ngModelChange)="isOverflowing(t)"></textarea>
```

Note that `ngModel` now only binds 1 way, rather than 2, as you've hooked up the other binding with `ngModelChange`.

See here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Comment: This is the correct answer. To make this work though, I had to add an else statement and actually do the assigning if things are OK.

Answer (score -2):

only for beginers:
if your using [(ngModel)]="input" function your page go to hide that time:
first step:
   open app.module.ts-->import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
second step:
    see below sampe page like app.module.ts imports:[BrowserModule ] you should add FormsModule like this imports:[BrowserModule,FormsModule]

then run your app ..working app right now...